# Add Existing Tag to Article in Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to add existing Tags to Articles.

My models:

```rb
# app/models/user.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :articles, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :tags, dependent: :destroy
end

# app/models/article.rb
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :tags
end

# app/models/tag.rb
class Tag < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :article
  has_many :articles
  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: { scope: :user_id }
end
```

By using the following in the console, I'm able to add a tag to an article.

```
> a = Article.last
> a.tags.create(name: "unread", user_id: "1")
> a.tags
  Tag Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" WHERE "tags"."article_id" = ?  [["article_id", 29]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Tag id: 6, name: "unread", user_id: 1, article_id: 29, created_at: "2020-12-28 16:05:36", updated_at: "2020-12-28 16:05:36", permalink: "unread">]>
```

If I try to add this same tag to different article using the same `.create`, I get a rollback error.

```
> a = Article.first
> a.tags.create(name: "unread", user_id: "1")
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Tag Exists? (0.1ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "tags" WHERE "tags"."name" = ? AND "tags"."user_id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["name", "unread"], ["user_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.0ms)  rollback transaction
```

Thinking the problem is the `.create` since that tag already exists, I tried this `first_or_create`, but that also errored.

```
> a.tags.first_or_create(name: "unread", user_id: "1")
  Tag Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" WHERE "tags"."article_id" = ? ORDER BY "tags"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["article_id", 52], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  Tag Exists? (0.1ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "tags" WHERE "tags"."name" = ? AND "tags"."user_id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["name", "unread"], ["user_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.3ms)  rollback transaction
```

How do I add an existing tag to an article?

**Edit:**

I've added a join table as [prescribed by Max](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65482363/3921815). This has allowed me to save tags to articles via the console.

```
> t = Tag.where(name: "rails", user_id: "1").first_or_create
  Tag Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" WHERE "tags"."name" = ? AND "tags"."user_id" = ? ORDER BY "tags"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["name", "rails"], ["user_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<Tag id: 8, name: "rails", user_id: 1, created_at: "2020-12-28 21:21:25", updated_at: "2020-12-28 21:21:25", permalink: "rails">
> a.tags << t
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  Article Tag Exists? (0.1ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "article_tags" WHERE "article_tags"."tag_id" = ? AND "article_tags"."article_id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["tag_id", 8], ["article_id", 29], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Article Tag Create (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "article_tags" ("article_id", "tag_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["article_id", 29], ["tag_id", 8], ["created_at", "2020-12-28 21:22:13.567187"], ["updated_at", "2020-12-28 21:22:13.567187"]]
   (17.9ms)  commit transaction
  Tag Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" INNER JOIN "article_tags" ON "tags"."id" = "article_tags"."tag_id" WHERE "article_tags"."article_id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["article_id", 29], ["LIMIT", 11]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Tag id: 6, name: "unread", user_id: 1, created_at: "2020-12-28 16:05:36", updated_at: "2020-12-28 16:05:36", permalink: "unread">, #<Tag id: 8, name: "rails", user_id: 1, created_at: "2020-12-28 21:21:25", updated_at: "2020-12-28 21:21:25", permalink: "rails">]>
```

I'm still unclear how to save this from the view.

I have a form in app/views/articles/edit.html.erb:

```
<%= form_with(model: @article, local: true) do |form| %>
  <%= form.label :tag_list, "Tags, separated by comma" %>
  <%= form.text_field :tag_list %>
  <%= form.submit "Update Tags" %>
<% end %>
```

In the Articles Controller I assume I'd want the following.

```rb
def edit
  @article.tags << Tag.where(name: "unread", user_id: "1").first_or_create
  @article.save!
end
```

...or perhaps I need to loop those tags in the model? Something like this:

```rb
# app/models/article.rb
def tag_list
  tags.map(&:name).join(", ")
end

def tag_list=(names)
  self.tags = names.split(",").map do |name|
    Tag.where(name: name.strip, user_id: current_user.id).first_or_create!
  end
end
```

```rb
# app/controllers/articles_controller.rb
def edit
  @article.tags << tag_list
  @article.save!
end
```

But this isn't working. How do I update the tags from a view?

**Edit:**

I've decided not to update tags by form, so I've marked [Max's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65482363/3921815) as the solution since he pointed me to the [Join Tables](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) which got me on the right track.

If you wish to update this for posterity, I'm sure they will appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a tag to ever belong to more then a single article you need a join table:

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :article_tags
  has_many :tags, through: :article_tags
end

# rails g model article_tag article:references tag:references
# make sure to add a unique index on article_id and tag_id
class ArticleTag < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :article
  belongs_to :tag
  validates_uniqueness_of :tag_id, scope: :article_id
end

class Tag < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :article_tags
  has_many :articles, through: :article_tags
end
```

This creates a [many to many association](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) between the two tables (an article can have multiple tags, and a tag can belong to multiple articles). This can also be done through `has_and_belongs_to_many` which does not have a join model but [has limited flexibility](https://flatironschool.com/blog/why-you-dont-need-has-and-belongs-to-many).

If you want to add an existing tag(s) to an article you can use the shovel operator:

```
a = Article.last
a.tags << Tag.first
a.tags << Tag.second
```

But usually you use the `tag_ids=` setter to set the association from an array of ids:

```
class ArticlesController
  def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)
    # ...
  end

  private
  def article_params
    require(:article)
      .permit(:title, :body, tag_ids: [])
  end
end
```

```
<%= form_with(model: @article) do |f| %>
  # ...
  <%= f.collection_checkboxes :tag_ids, Tag.all, :id, :name %>
<% end %>
```

`tag_ids: []` permits an array of ids.

This will automatically add/remove rows in the join table depending on what the user checks.

Comment: I don't understand *why* I need the join table, but I've created it as you've suggested. I'm still getting the same rollback errors trying to add an existing tag (`a.tags.create(name: "unread", user_id: "1")`). Also, the tag in my original question (with id: 6) is no longer attached to the article it was. I don't know how to use the information in your answer to get me where I want to go. Could you explain more how I can add an existing tag to an article?

Comment: The reason you need a join table is that if you place the 'article_id' column on the tags table it will only ever contain one id. As soon as your relation is not one to one or one to many you need a join table that can store a row for each connection between the two tables.

Comment: I would suggest you read the guides article on associations and backtrack a bit and start fresh on this feature.

Comment: I think I've wrapped my head around the idea of a join table. Thank you for pointing in the right direction there. I'm able to get this working from the console when I hand-type the `name` and `user_id`, but I can't get it to save from a view. I've updated my question.